# When did Chrome started to support timezone offset for Intl.DateTimeFormat()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internationalization

On my Chromium 121 the following `Intl.DateTimeFormat` works fine:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
      dateStyle: 'long',
      timeStyle: 'long',
      timeZone: '+0500',
    }).format(new Date());

> 'February 18, 2024 at 3:42:40 AM GMT+5'
```

The same on a Chrome Headless 114.0.5673.0 fails with `Invalid time zone specified: +0500`.

Could help me point out when/in which version this timezone format got supported ?

Answer (score 0):

From everything I can find, it should have been [supported as of version 24](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#browser_compatibility).

I also tested your code on the latest Firefox and it worked fine.

Granted, [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezone) states it MUST support GMT and MAY support IANA time zones, but does not say anything about offsets:

> The only value implementations must recognize is "UTC"; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations may also recognize the time zone names of the IANA time zone database, such as "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York".

So technically, implementations could support ***no*** time zones at all, but the vast majority of apps should support the IANA time zones.

You can try using the IANA timezone offset name:

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    dateStyle: 'long',
    timeStyle: 'long',
    timeZone: 'Etc/GMT-5',
}).format(new Date());
```

```
"February 18, 2024 at 3:42:40 AM GMT+5"
```

If that does not work, it is more likely some kind of issue in your setup. Also note that I used the opposite offset (-5 instead of +5). This is just how the IANA timezone Etc offset names are designed: they are the opposite of what the actual offset is (Etc/GMT-5 is actually +0500 and Etc/GMT+5 is actually -0500).

Comment: The issue with `Etc/GMT` it's it only supports full hours. India for example with `GMT+5:30` cannot be represented with that

Comment: I mostly provided that for you to test and see if it worked in comparison to using an offset. In reality, you shouldn't even be using an offset but a timezone such `Asia/Calcutta`.

Comment: If you can't get any time zone to work, I would look at ICU on the machine you are running headless on. Chromium and other browsers use the ICU library for the Intl namespace classes. If it is not installed, not able to be accessed, not setup properly, is old or has out-of-date data, it could change what time zones and format are available.